# Free diskspace innoDB Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am facing a problem with the diskspace of my MYSQL server. I got 4% of disk space left (16Gb). And I noticed one of my tables is un-used and carries 100 Gb. So I want to delete/drop it.

However, deleting it only fills up the 4% (as it creates logs and journals and stuff). What I understood is that the solution would be to delete the content of the table and run Table Optimize to free the diskspace.

However, this won't work as Table Optimize creates a copy of the 100Gb (and I don't have them).

A other solution I read about is to dump and re-upload the DDB. I would like not to do this if possible (downtime is an issue).

Is there any other solution? I know you shouldn't rm the datafiles of mysql ; but is there any way do drop a table and freeing the diskspace without Table Optimize or dumping the DDB?

My innodb_file_per_table is on "ON"

Comment: *"The table rebuild triggered by OPTIMIZE TABLE and performed under the cover by `ALTER TABLE ... FORCE` is completed in place. "*  Try `ALTER TABLE tbl_name  FORCE ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE` or `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB  ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE` to rebuild the table.

Comment: Won't this copy the data to a tmp table? Because if it's the case, I will crash my server as I don't have the diskspace to copy the data.

Comment: *"Won't this copy the data to a tmp table? "* **INPLACE: Operations avoid copying table data but may rebuild the table in place**. An exclusive metadata lock on the table may be taken briefly during preparation and execution phases of the operation. Typically, concurrent DML is supported.  see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I am sorry, my lack of english skills prevents me from understanding "rebuild the table in place". What do you mean by rebuild? Does it drop the data, create a shema without re-inserting the data?

Comment: how to explain it more easy?  I assume the MySQL manual means with "rebuild the table in place" a internal copy off a record to a other position in the table file and remove (death) unused tuples to keep the structure more smaller.. Just like the disk formatting tool does more or less.

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_file_per_table = OFF`:

`DELETE FROM TABLE` removes the rows, but saves them in case of a crash so that it can restore them.

`TRUNCATE TABLE` recreates the table as empty.  You end up with an empty table but no crash recovery. and no disk space consumed.

`DROP TABLE` removes the table and its space.  You probably wanted this.

`innodb_file_per_table = OFF`:

None of the above releases disk space back to the OS, only to future InnoDB inserts (etc).